# How to install waterfox for all users?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, tar

I was looking to install Waterfox for all users on Ubuntu 20.04. I understand a very similar question already exists however none of the replies to it solve my problem.

I downloaded Waterfox which came in a tar.bz archive. I understand I can extract it to my home folder and add a desktop shortcut that I can pin to my taskbar.

However this only installs it for my user. There is no install script so how do I install it for all users? I figured I can probably dump it somewhere in /opt but that's obviously not where it's supposed to go. What's the proper way of doing this?

Also, I'm not looking to add unofficial repositories, I'd like to manually install it.

Comment: Strangely, there's a plan for that. See https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml , the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard.